# "Now that I think of it..."

Tags: expression

Wie würde man diesen Ausdruck ins Deutsch übersetzen? Meiner Einschätzung nach wäre es

> Jetzt, wo ich daran denke, müssen wir nicht bis den 27. einen aussuchen.
>
> (=Now that I think about it, we don't need to pick one out until the 27th)

Für mich klingt das aber ein bisschen komisch.

Comment: Aus den Antworten erkenne ich grade, dass dein Kontext nicht 100% klar ist. "jetzt, wo ich daran denke" ist zwar äquivalent zu "mir fällt gerade ein", aber ich meine dass das gar nicht dein Kontext ist, zumindest suggeriert mir das der andere Teil deines Satzes. Du willst imho nicht sagen "I remember" sondern "upon further reflection", oder liege ich da falsch? Kannst du das vllt noch mal klar stellen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast. Ein Muttersprachler würde es folgendermaßen sagen:

> Jetzt, wo ich **d(a)rüber nachdenke**, müssen wir nicht bis **zum** 27. einen aussuchen.

Außerdem kannst du die Zeit auch ins Perfekt setzen (genau genommen ist das die wahrscheinlichere Variante):

> Jetzt, wo ich drüber nachdenke, müssen wir nicht bis zum 27. einen **ausgesucht haben**.

Answer (score 1):

Em1 gives the phrase `Jetzt wo ich d(a)rüber nachdenke`, which is the most literal translation. But the whole phrase is rather rare in German. There are other phrases more common, that express similar things:

> Übrigens = By the way
>
> Mir fällt gerade ein = It comes to my mind at the moment

Comment: Wenn "jetzt wo ich drüber nachdenke" selten in Deutschland ist, gilt die Gegend, in der ich lebe, wohl nicht zu Deutschland ;)

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28Jetzt+wo+ich+dr%C3%BCber+nachdenke%2BJetzt+wo+ich+dar%C3%BCber+nachdenke%29%2C+Mir+f%C3%A4llt+gerade+ein&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMir%20f%C3%A4llt%20gerade%20ein%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Dieses ngram ist in keinster Weise repäsentativ. Dieses ngram erweckt den Eindruck, es würde 0 (in Worten Null) Belege vorliegen. Das sollte dir schon zu Denken geben, dass es Humbug ist. Wolltest du ein repräsentitives ngram erstellen, müsste du mit Regulären Ausdrücken arbeiten, leider ist die Unterstützung von ngram zu schwach, da sobald du einen Platzhalter einbaust, kannst du bspw. keinen Vergleich mit einem anderen String machen. - Es stimmt, dass es mehr Hits für "mir fällt gerade ein" generell gibt, aber dein ngram ist wirklich ein absoluter Reinfall. Sorry.

Comment: So, jetzt mal eines, wo ich dich um Welten schlage: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(so+dr%C3%BCber+nachdenke+%2B+ich+dr%C3%BCber+nachdenke+%2B+so+dar%C3%BCber+nachdenke+%2B+ich+dar%C3%BCber+nachdenke)%2C+(mir+f%C3%A4llt+gerade+ein+%2B+mir+f%C3%A4llt+ein)&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28so%20dr%C3%BCber%20nachdenke%20%2B%20ich%20dr%C3%BCber%20nachdenke%20%2B%20so%20dar%C3%BCber%20nachdenke%20%2B%20ich%20dar%C3%BCber%20nachdenke%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28mir%20f%C3%A4llt%20gerade%20ein%20%2B%20mir%20f%C3%A4llt%20ein%29%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Ist übrigens genau so wenig repräsentativ wie deines.

Comment: @Em1 Ja, denn deine Phrasen können gut mit voranstehenden Wörtern leicht andere Bedeutungen haben (`wenn ich so drüber nachdenke`, `wie ich so drüber nachdenke`)

Answer (score 0):

The shortest translation would be `apropos` in the context of reminding somebody of something while talking about a similar subject.

> Wir müssen noch einen Weihnachtsbaum kaufen!
>   Apropos, wir brauchen auch noch Christbaumschmuck.

If you really *really* want to say that you actually thought about something more closely and came to a conclusion, you'd say:

> Ich habe darüber nachgedacht, und ...
>   Wo ich so darüber nachdenke ...

If something jumps to your mind and you want to tell someone because it is somewhat important, you'd actually say:

> Jetzt, wo ich gerade dran denke ...
>   Mir fällt gerade ein: ...